# Clear text box on form after a few seconds

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to find the best way to have a text box displays a message everytime another control (a button) is pushed.  Each time the button is pushed, the message will change and that message should show in my text box. The trick I would like to do is after the user stops pressing the button, that after a certain period (3 seconds) the text box will disappear..  (perhaps the message can be deleted).  What is the correct event to use ?

Basically, for each control named 'msgPrincipio' in the code below, i would like that message to appear within the text box for 3 seconds and then disappear:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()

Dim intTimerStart As Integer, intTimerUsed As Integer
Dim intCountdown As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_Handle
  If Me!msgPrincipio <> "" Then
    If intTimerStart > 0 Then
        intTimerUsed = CLng((Timer / 60) - intTimerStart)
    Else
        intTimerStart = CLng(Timer / 60)
    End If

     If intCountdown > 3 Then
        Me!msgPrincipio = ""
    End If

    intCountdown = intCountdown + 1

  End If
Err_Exit:       Exit Sub
Err_Handle:     Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The correct event to use is the Form `Timer`.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am not sure what the event to choose is. This is a control on the form. The form needs to stay on but the timer needs to be activated the moment in which the object (text box) undergoes a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim intTimerStart as Integer, intTimerUsed as Integer
Dim intCountdown as Integer

Sub Form_Timer()

On Error GoTo Err_Handle
  If Me!MyBox <> "" Then
    If intTimerStart > 0 Then
        intTimerUsed = CLng((Timer / 60) - intTimerStart)
    Else
        intTimerStart = CLng(Timer / 60)
    End If

    If intCountdown > 3 Then
        Me!MyBox = ""
    End If

    intCountdown = intCountdown + 1

  End If
Err_Exit:       Exit Sub
Err_Handle:     Resume Next
End Sub
```

You also need to go to the form's design view and set the "Timer Interval" property on the form to an appropriate value.  This code assumes `1,000` (1 second).

You almost *never* want to use `Resume Next`, but it's good here -- the goal is to pass through this block of code as seamlessly as possible. (Which you can accomplish with simple `On Error Resume Next` at the start -- but I don't like seeing it in my code that way, not one bit.  I do this so I'll easily recognize it's by design, not carelessness.)

### New to Access' Form Timer?

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    Debug.Print Time        ' Update time display.
End Sub
```

Put this code in the form's VBA module.  Return to the form design view and switch to form view.  Now go back to VBA and check your `Immediate` window.  You should see evidence the form timer event is kicking.  **Note the Timer property of the form (found under form properties, design view) must not be blank or zero.  It needs an entry to kick.**

Comment: What is the event to attach this to.. The timer event on the form?

Comment: Yes.  This is revealed by the line `Sub Form_Timer()`.

Comment: I dont understand how to trigger the routine.

Comment: Private Sub Form_Timer()


Dim intTimerStart As Integer, intTimerUsed As Integer
Dim intCountdown As Integer


On Error GoTo Err_Handle
  If Me!msgPrincipio <> "" Then
    If intTimerStart > 0 Then
        intTimerUsed = CLng((Timer / 60) - intTimerStart)
    Else
        intTimerStart = CLng(Timer / 60)
    End If

    If intCountdown > 3 Then
        Me!msgPrincipio = ""
    End If

    intCountdown = intCountdown + 1

  End If
Err_Exit:       Exit Sub
Err_Handle:     Resume Next
End Sub



End Sub

Comment: I added some hints.  Check http://www.blueclaw-db.com/access_event_programming/timer.htm

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you..   I of course added the Me.TimerInterval=3000 to the on load event of the form. Not that you gave a finger and I will take an arm but may I ask, is it possible to make the disappearing act of the text box more elagant??  Perhaps, it can flash once in a soft manner before disappearing??  Its a bit abrupt the way the disappearing takes place.

Comment: Sorry one more question (more important than the previous).  Is it possible to pause or put on hold the timer. Basically, I want it so that the user while scrolling through options (by pusing a button control) does not get interupted by the execution of the on timer event which basically wipes out the message box which the user is viewing while scrolling.

Comment: Yes and yes.  I suggest separate posts for these.

Answer (score 0):

Using C#

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{  private Timer x = new Timer();

public Form1()
{
      x.Interval = (6000);  //1 second = 1000
      x.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTask); 
      x.Start();
}

private void TimerTask(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      TextboxName.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

To set a label content dispear automatically: https://gamespec.tech/how-to-clear-textbox-after-few-seconds-in-c-sharp/#3-set-label-content-and-make-it-disappear-automatically